# Want to remove index.php from the URL

Tags: php, url-rewrite, server-setup, base-url, .htaccess

Hi My site name is xpressbuyer.com.

I have tried almost all solution, but nothing seems to be working. Below things i have done.

1. Add code in `.htaccess`
2. Set *Use Web Server Rewrites* to *YES* in Search Engine Optimisation tab
3. Added

   ```
   <directory "="" var="" www="" html"="">
   AllowOverride All
   </directory>
   ```

in `.htaccess` file.

Could you please direct me to find a solution for this?

Comment: In admin panel goto system->configuration->left side(general)->web-> Use Web Server Rewrites-> set yes

Comment: clear your cache and session

Comment: I did it already but still the issue remains same.

Comment: Is your server configured properly to handle mod_rewrite ?

Comment: I have enable mod_rewrite by command "a2enmod rewrite" & it gives message that "Module rewrite is already enabled". Let me know if there is any other setting

Comment: when i see /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load, you can see the same in this screen shot http://screencast.com/t/FZfq0n9B

Answer (score 0):

Please check your webserver config file (e.g. apache2.conf) if  `AllowOverride All` is set (default is None) and restart the webserver.

Otherwise the .htaccess settings are not evaluated.

Comment: Plz check this apache2.conf file screen shot: http://screencast.com/t/ceOUMcAEB2R    At where should i make changes? My all files are into /var/www/html/. Can u plz suggest?

Comment: In the last part, `<Directory /var/www/>` as I guess the mentioned .htaccess file is located in /var/www/html/.htaccess.

If you change it to `AllowOverride All` the settings of the .htaccess file will overwrite the server settings in the apache2.conf file. Hope this helps you ;)

Comment: I think in addition you have to define the rewrite itself to make from `http://yourmagentoshop.com/index.php -> http://yourmagentoshop.com`. Here you can find an accepted solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls

Comment: When i change to AllowOverride All, it stops working and giving me 500 internal server error.

Comment: For my every other pages on site, it gives me this error http://screencast.com/t/B6F2s7WdB   Do you think, it is related to port 443 error?

Comment: Does it work for a non https url e.g. the shopping cart, so just click "My Cart" ... does the rewrite work?

Comment: when, i try to access by using "http" , it redirects to "https"